# Hi I'm new to JavaScript, and just started making some basic JS Projects and encountered some errors

Tags: javascript, frontend

The Problem: the first time my code runs perfectly fine, and when I reset it through reset button, it reset all the output in Document, but problem comes here when I run the code again by clicking on "CLICK ME" button it wont run and shows the error(Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null ageCalculator.) ["ageCalculator is Function Name"]

CODE: Please Refer the code below..>>>

Screenshot of error:

[image: 1]

```js
function ageCalculator(){
  let birthyear = prompt('what is your birth year ?');

/*................FOR AGE IN YEAR.......................*/
  let ageInyear = (2020-birthyear);  //formula to calculate age by years.
  let ageh5 = document.createElement('p');
  let yearAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageInyear + ' years old.');
  ageh5.setAttribute('id','ageyear');
  ageh5.appendChild(yearAnswer);
  document.getElementById('ageinyears').appendChild(ageh5);
  //console.log('year success');//display in console

  /*................FOR AGE IN MONTH.......................*/
  let ageMonth =(ageInyear * 12);
  let agemon = document.createElement('p');
  let monthAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageMonth + ' old');
  agemon.setAttribute('id','ageinMonth');
  agemon.appendChild(monthAnswer);
  document.getElementById('ageInMonth').appendChild(agemon);
  //console.log('month success');

  /*................FOR AGE IN DAYS.......................*/
 let ageInDays = (2020-birthyear)*365;  //formula for calculating age in days.
 let agep = document.createElement('p');  //creating p or (h3,h4,h5) tag through js
 let daysAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are '+ ageInDays + ' days.')  //message that will be displayed on output.
 agep.setAttribute('id', 'ageinDays'); // creating id to h4and giving id name ageInDays.
 agep.appendChild(daysAnswer); //h5 child (sentence) display.
 document.getElementById('ageInDays').appendChild(agep);  //targeting id from HTML doc and adding h4 attribute to it (which is created in JS).
 //console.log('day success '); //display in console.

 /*................FOR AGE IN HOURS.......................*/
  let agehours = (ageInyear * 12 * 30 * 24); //formula to calculate age in hours
  let agehr = document.createElement('p');
  let hrAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + agehours + ' hours old');
  agehr.setAttribute('id','ageinhr');
  agehr.appendChild(hrAnswer);
  document.getElementById('ageinhours').appendChild(agehr);
  //console.log('hour success');//display in console

  /*................FOR AGE IN MINUTES.......................*/
 let ageminute = (ageInyear * 12 * 30 * 24 * 60);
 let agemin = document.createElement('p');
 let minAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageminute + ' minute old');
 agemin.setAttribute('id','minuteage');
 agemin.appendChild(minAnswer);
 document.getElementById('ageinminutes').appendChild(agemin);
 //console.log('minute success');

  /*................FOR AGE IN SECONDS.......................*/
  let agesec = (ageInyear * 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
  let ageinsec = document.createElement('p');
  let secAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + agesec + ' seconds old');
  ageinsec.setAttribute('id','secINage');
  ageinsec.appendChild(secAnswer);
  document.getElementById('ageinsecounds').appendChild(ageinsec);
  //console.log('second success');
}


function reset(){
  document.getElementById('ageinyears').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageInDays').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageInMonth').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinhours').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinminutes').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinsecounds').remove();
  console.log('reset  success');
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.flex-container-result div{
  margin-top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-container-result label{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
   <h2>Age Calclator.</h2>
   <div class="flex-container">
     <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-5" onclick="ageCalculator()"><b>click me</b></button>
     </div>

     <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-4" onclick="reset()"><b>Reset</b></button>
     </div>

 </div>

   <div class="flex-container-result">
     <div id="ageinyears">
       <label>age in years :&nbsp  </label>
     </div>

     <div id="ageInDays">
       <label>age in days :&nbsp  </label>
      </div>

      <div id="ageInMonth">
        <label>age in month :&nbsp  </label>
      </div>


      <div id="ageinhours">
        <label>age in hours :&nbsp  </label>
      </div>

      <div id="ageinminutes">
        <label>age in minutes :&nbsp  </label>
      </div>

      <div id="ageinsecounds">
        <label>age in secounds :&nbsp  </label>
      </div>
   </div>

</div>

  <script src="proj1.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Write a title that summarizes the specific problem** - The title is the first thing potential answerers will see, and if your title isn't interesting, they won't read the rest."_

Comment: Snippet seems to be working fine. Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: the snippet works just fine, think it's a you machine's problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is all here.

```
function reset(){
  document.getElementById('ageinyears').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageInDays').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageInMonth').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinhours').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinminutes').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinsecounds').remove();
  console.log('reset  success');
}
```

Change to

```
function reset(){
  document.getElementById('ageyear').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinDays').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinMonth').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinhr').remove();
  document.getElementById('minuteage').remove();
  document.getElementById('secINage').remove();
  console.log('reset  success');
}
```

**Let me explain**

1. Initially each parent (`div[id="ageinyears"], div[id="ageInDays"], div[id="ageInMonth"], div[id="ageinhours"], div[id="ageinminutes"], div[id="ageinminutes"], div[id="ageinsecounds"]`) have only 1 child = `Lable`
2. when the user clicks on the button `click me`, you have logic to give birth to another child for each parent; New childs = (`p[id="ageyear"], p[id="ageinDays"], p[id="ageinMonth"], p[id="ageinhr"], p[id="minuteage"], p[id="secINage"]`)
3. **The problem is**... When the user clicks on the button `reset` using remove() method, you are commanding to kill `few parents + few newborn babies` instead of ONLY the **newborn babies** of the `parents`.. and all the newborn babies are required for your logic **ID**.appendChild() + **Bonus:**... This unethical Error/killing is happening just because of the wrong Ids.

**Additional Help**

You should handle the `Reset` button properly; I mean something like...

1. Initial state of Reset: disabled

   ```
   <button type="button" id="reset" class="btn btn-danger mr-4" onclick="reset()" disabled><b>Reset</b></button>
   ```
2. Enable it after a successful age calculation

   ```
   document.getElementById("reset").disabled = false;
   ```
3. Disable it again after the reset

   ```
   document.getElementById("reset").disabled = true;
   ```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.flex-container-result div{
  margin-top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-container-result label{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<body>
  <div class="container">
   <h2>Age Calclator.</h2>
   <div class="flex-container">
     <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-5" onclick="ageCalculator()"><b>click me</b></button>
     </div>

     <div>
          <button type="button" id="reset" class="btn btn-danger mr-4" onclick="reset()" disabled><b>Reset</b></button>
     </div>

 </div>

   <div class="flex-container-result">
     <div id="ageinyears">
       <label>age in years :&nbsp  </label>
     </div>

     <div id="ageInDays">
       <label>age in days :&nbsp  </label>
      </div>

      <div id="ageInMonth">
        <label>age in month :&nbsp  </label>
      </div>


      <div id="ageinhours">
        <label>age in hours :&nbsp  </label>
      </div>

      <div id="ageinminutes">
        <label>age in minutes :&nbsp  </label>
      </div>

      <div id="ageinsecounds">
        <label>age in secounds :&nbsp  </label>
      </div>
   </div>

</div>

  <script src="proj1.js"></script>
</body>
<script id="jsbin-javascript">
function ageCalculator(){
  let birthyear = prompt('what is your birth year ?');

/*................FOR AGE IN YEAR.......................*/
  let ageInyear = (2020-birthyear);  //formula to calculate age by years.
  let ageh5 = document.createElement('p');
  let yearAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageInyear + ' years old.');
  ageh5.setAttribute('id','ageyear');
  ageh5.appendChild(yearAnswer);
  document.getElementById('ageinyears').appendChild(ageh5);
  //console.log('year success');//display in console

  /*................FOR AGE IN MONTH.......................*/
  let ageMonth =(ageInyear * 12);
  let agemon = document.createElement('p');
  let monthAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageMonth + ' old');
  agemon.setAttribute('id','ageinMonth');
  agemon.appendChild(monthAnswer);
  document.getElementById('ageInMonth').appendChild(agemon);
  //console.log('month success');

  /*................FOR AGE IN DAYS.......................*/
 let ageInDays = (2020-birthyear)*365;  //formula for calculating age in days.
 let agep = document.createElement('p');  //creating p or (h3,h4,h5) tag through js
 let daysAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are '+ ageInDays + ' days.')  //message that will be displayed on output.
 agep.setAttribute('id', 'ageinDays'); // creating id to h4and giving id name ageInDays.
 agep.appendChild(daysAnswer); //h5 child (sentence) display.
 document.getElementById('ageInDays').appendChild(agep);  //targeting id from HTML doc and adding h4 attribute to it (which is created in JS).
 //console.log('day success '); //display in console.

 /*................FOR AGE IN HOURS.......................*/
  let agehours = (ageInyear * 12 * 30 * 24); //formula to calculate age in hours
  let agehr = document.createElement('p');
  let hrAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + agehours + ' hours old');
  agehr.setAttribute('id','ageinhr');
  agehr.appendChild(hrAnswer);
  document.getElementById('ageinhours').appendChild(agehr);
  //console.log('hour success');//display in console

  /*................FOR AGE IN MINUTES.......................*/
 let ageminute = (ageInyear * 12 * 30 * 24 * 60);
 let agemin = document.createElement('p');
 let minAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageminute + ' minute old');
 agemin.setAttribute('id','minuteage');
 agemin.appendChild(minAnswer);
 document.getElementById('ageinminutes').appendChild(agemin);
 //console.log('minute success');

  /*................FOR AGE IN SECONDS.......................*/
  let agesec = (ageInyear * 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
  let ageinsec = document.createElement('p');
  let secAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + agesec + ' seconds old');
  ageinsec.setAttribute('id','secINage');
  ageinsec.appendChild(secAnswer);
  document.getElementById('ageinsecounds').appendChild(ageinsec);

  document.getElementById("reset").disabled = false;

  //console.log('second success');
}


function reset(){
  
  document.getElementById('ageyear').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinDays').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinMonth').remove();
  document.getElementById('ageinhr').remove();
  document.getElementById('minuteage').remove();
  document.getElementById('secINage').remove();
  console.log('reset  success');
  document.getElementById("reset").disabled = true;
  
 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** Yes, this will solve your problem but, seriously this is not the proper way of handling things in real-time but `Squint is better than blindness right...` so as of now you can use this piece, but, I suggest you to focus more on things by analysing real-time scenarios and code issues :)

Comment: can u guide me how can I remove the value of "1st clickme " when I hit the "Click ME" 2nd time without resetting, Acutally if we hit click me button 2nd time without reset,the output value of 2nd click  is shown besdie with the output of first click.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? I can help you.

Comment: 1st try-   click on "CLICK ME " to get following ouptuts. then generally we click on "RESET BUTTON"  to rese the pannel(document). BUT INSTEAD : id we don't click on "RESET BUTTON"  and directly clicked "CLICK ME " the new value comes with previous output values , The question is 'how can we remove the previous values in document without hitting" RESET BUTTON" instead Hitting "CLICK ME" and all previous output must be replace with new one's

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code.

When you resest it you removed html element from document. And second time when you want to calculate and write result to element there is no that element. And it gives you error.  You need just clear it.

just replace

`document.getElementById('ageinyears').remove();`

to

`document.getElementById('ageinyears').innerHTML = "your initial html code"`

```js
    function ageCalculator(){
      let birthyear = prompt('what is your birth year ?');

    /*................FOR AGE IN YEAR.......................*/
      let ageInyear = (2020-birthyear);  //formula to calculate age by years.
      let ageh5 = document.createElement('p');
      let yearAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageInyear + ' years old.');
      ageh5.setAttribute('id','ageyear');
      ageh5.appendChild(yearAnswer);
      document.getElementById('ageinyears').appendChild(ageh5);
      //console.log('year success');//display in console

      /*................FOR AGE IN MONTH.......................*/
      let ageMonth =(ageInyear * 12);
      let agemon = document.createElement('p');
      let monthAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageMonth + ' old');
      agemon.setAttribute('id','ageinMonth');
      agemon.appendChild(monthAnswer);
      document.getElementById('ageInMonth').appendChild(agemon);
      //console.log('month success');

      /*................FOR AGE IN DAYS.......................*/
     let ageInDays = (2020-birthyear)*365;  //formula for calculating age in days.
     let agep = document.createElement('p');  //creating p or (h3,h4,h5) tag through js
     let daysAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are '+ ageInDays + ' days.')  //message that will be displayed on output.
     agep.setAttribute('id', 'ageinDays'); // creating id to h4and giving id name ageInDays.
     agep.appendChild(daysAnswer); //h5 child (sentence) display.
     document.getElementById('ageInDays').appendChild(agep);  //targeting id from HTML doc and adding h4 attribute to it (which is created in JS).
     //console.log('day success '); //display in console.

     /*................FOR AGE IN HOURS.......................*/
      let agehours = (ageInyear * 12 * 30 * 24); //formula to calculate age in hours
      let agehr = document.createElement('p');
      let hrAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + agehours + ' hours old');
      agehr.setAttribute('id','ageinhr');
      agehr.appendChild(hrAnswer);
      document.getElementById('ageinhours').appendChild(agehr);
      //console.log('hour success');//display in console

      /*................FOR AGE IN MINUTES.......................*/
     let ageminute = (ageInyear * 12 * 30 * 24 * 60);
     let agemin = document.createElement('p');
     let minAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageminute + ' minute old');
     agemin.setAttribute('id','minuteage');
     agemin.appendChild(minAnswer);
     document.getElementById('ageinminutes').appendChild(agemin);
     //console.log('minute success');

      /*................FOR AGE IN SECONDS.......................*/
      let agesec = (ageInyear * 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60);
      let ageinsec = document.createElement('p');
      let secAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + agesec + ' seconds old');
      ageinsec.setAttribute('id','secINage');
      ageinsec.appendChild(secAnswer);
      document.getElementById('ageinsecounds').appendChild(ageinsec);
      //console.log('second success');
    }


    function reset(){
      document.getElementById('ageinyears').innerHTML = "<label>age in years :&nbsp  </label>";
      document.getElementById('ageInDays').innerHTML = "<label>age in days :&nbsp  </label>";
      document.getElementById('ageInMonth').innerHTML = "<label>age in month :&nbsp  </label>";
      document.getElementById('ageinhours').innerHTML = "<label>age in hours :&nbsp  </label>";
      document.getElementById('ageinminutes').innerHTML = "<label>age in minutes :&nbsp  </label>";
      document.getElementById('ageinsecounds').innerHTML = "<label>age in secounds :&nbsp  </label>";
      console.log('reset  success');
    }
```

```css
 *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .flex-container{
      display: flex;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 15px;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-around;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .flex-container-result div{
      margin-top: 2px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      display: flex;
      padding: 10px;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .flex-container-result label{
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
      <div class="container">
       <h2>Age Calclator.</h2>
       <div class="flex-container">
         <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-5" onclick="ageCalculator()"><b>click me</b></button>
         </div>

         <div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mr-4" onclick="reset()"><b>Reset</b></button>
         </div>

     </div>

       <div class="flex-container-result">
         <div id="ageinyears">
           <label>age in years :&nbsp  </label>
         </div>

         <div id="ageInDays">
           <label>age in days :&nbsp  </label>
          </div>

          <div id="ageInMonth">
            <label>age in month :&nbsp  </label>
          </div>


          <div id="ageinhours">
            <label>age in hours :&nbsp  </label>
          </div>

          <div id="ageinminutes">
            <label>age in minutes :&nbsp  </label>
          </div>

          <div id="ageinsecounds">
            <label>age in secounds :&nbsp  </label>
          </div>
       </div>

    </div>

      <script src="proj1.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: thanks @ThomasRyan now the code works very good without and errors, Thank you so much for the help